# How to setup VPN on Windows start

Tags: windows, service, vpn, authentication

Need to setup VPN on windows start, without User logon (Like a service).
does it  possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows 7:

```
Create a scheduled task named "Auto VPN" or something similar
   Tick the Run whether  user is logged  on or not   
   Tick the Run with highest privileges
   Select Configure for Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2 in the Configure For drop down box   
   Create a the trigger for the task and set the Begin the task drop down to At startup
   Create an action for the task and set the action to Start a program
      Set the Program/script to c:\windows\system32\rasdial.exe
      Put the name of the connection to be made in the Add Arguments box*
         *If the name contains spaces you will need to enclose the name in quotation marks
         *You may need to additional rasdial parameters to the Add Arguments box dependant on the connection properties
   Clear all task Conditions
```

The above was found **[here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-automatically-connect-to-a-vpn-in-windows-7/65d5bbd3-f946-4755-9ac9-943651e0e556)**.

You didn't specify the Operating System version, so I had no choice but to look for a general solution, rather than answer you directly.